# Since I wrote a route for a specific Action of a Controller, do I need to write a route for all Actions inside the Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

I'm writing few routes for my MVC application. I have the following routes for my application:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The route above is used when I want to access default values like:

**www.servicili.com/budget/edit/1**

**www.servicili.com/professional/view/234**

But, I create the following route for a specific purpose:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Perfil",
                url: "{UsuApelido}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Perfil", action = "Index"}
            );
```

the route above, is used to access the URL profile of a "plumber" for example:
**www.servicili.com/MarkZuckberg**

the profile details are on the controller **Perfil** and Action **Index**, however, since I wrote this route, all other actions aren't working.

For example: If I try to access the **Index** action inside another controller, it redirect to  **Index** of **Perfil**.

--
The question is: Since I wrote a route for a specific Action of a Controller, do I need to write a route for all Actions inside the Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem try like this,

First define constraint,

```
public class PlumberUrlConstraint: IRouteConstraint
{
   public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
   {
      var db = new YourDbContext();
      if (values[parameterName] != null)
      {
        var UsuApelido = values[parameterName].ToString();
        return db.Plumbers.Any(p => p.Name == UsuApelido);
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Define two routes, put "Default" route at 2nd position

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Perfil",
            url: "{*UsuApelido}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Perfil", action = "Index"},
            constraints: new { UsuApelido = new PlumberUrlConstraint() }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now if you have an 'Index' action in 'Perfil' Controller, you can get plumber name like this,

```
public ActionResult Index(string UsuApelido)
{
  //load the content from db with UsuApelido
  //display the content with view
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Need only to fix the code and add } in the end of the Constring: new... Do you know a link to get more reference about how to learn create routes in MVC? tks very much